# Is this even possible? Browser automation with jquery?

Tags: jquery

My friend want to make the following program on the web

Open in new window a browser, say google.com. Wait for 3 seconds for the page to be fully loaded. Find a search form. When search form is found, insert search term, say hotel. Automatically search stuff.

Can that be done with jquery?

Basically it's browser automation with jquery.

Can that be done.

Basically if user go to http://mydomainname.com/?search=hotel I want the user browser to automatically open another window that contain a search form and I want the user to search for such keywords.

Users need to be able to click for us to get paid and we won't automate that. But we want to automate the search.

So it's like automated click, except that rather than clicking we're just searching and hence don't commit fraud.

Comment: It can be done without a browser and with a serverside language, but with jQuery alone in a browser, nope it can't as javascript has a same-origin policy and Google has headers that block access.

Comment: You're probably looking for [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Usually you will use actual automation software for that (and for testing) such as [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/).

If you did want to do this in pure javascript (or with jQuery which is just a js library) then you would need to make a browser extension. A browser extension could handle the type of automation you are seeking by using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You generally won't be able to manipulate the status of a thirdparty site using webpage-based javascript such as jQuery from another domain, such as `google.com` (unless that site agrees to it through some kind of `postMessage` api). See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

There's a few caveats to that:

- It's sometimes possible to get around this restriction by proxying the content of the thirdparty domain through a local server, to make it appear as though the content is being loaded locally. Then you could augment it with your own javascript (`iframe`s loaded in this way have accessible content because it appears local). **This is generally a bad idea** - people don't appreciate you representing their content as if it were your own (not to mention all the potential technical obstacles to trying this).
- You could perform this kind of browser automation through some browser controlling application, like selenium. [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) has a [nodeJS](http://nodejs.org/) implementation, which is javascript, but not DOM-based webpage javascript.
- If the site you're attempting to manipulate *agrees to be manipulated*, you could implement `postMessage` callbacks between the two sites. `postMessage` allows you to create a communication channel between two separate sites over local javascript calls, thus messages can be sent between the two which could facilitate what you're asking for. See: [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage)

If you just want your site to proxy searches onto google then you could map your search url to google's, i.e `yoursite.com?s=search-str` to `google.com/?q=search-str` - however you will have **no** control over what they do from there on. Even if you `iframe` google, you won't know where they've gone or what they're doing beyond directing them to google itself.